# How can I cancel Data Binding changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a ListView that contains objects. When the user selects an item for editing, a form is opened where he can make the changes. Currently, when the user closes the form after making changes the original object in the ListView is updated, even though he closed the form without clicking Save. How can I prevent data binding when the user wants to cancel changes?

---

```
<!--xaml-->
<TextBox x:Name="tbFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=MyObject.first_name}" />
<TextBox x:Name="tbLastName" Text="{Binding Path=MyObject.last_name}"  />
```

---

```
public class MyObject {
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
     public string LastName {get; set;}
}

List<MyObject> listOfObjects = new List<MyObject>();
```

---

```
//user selects what he wants to edit from a ListView and clicks the Edit button
//the object is passed to a new form where he can make the desired changes.
//the editing form is automatically populated with the object thanks to data binding! this is good! :)
```

---

```
//Edit Button Clicked:
EditorForm ef = new EditorForm(listOfObjects[listview.SelectedIndex]);
ef.ShowDialog();
```

---

```
private MyObject myObject;

public EditorForm(MyObject obj) {
    InitializeComponent();
    myObject = obj;
    DataContext = this;
}
```

---

```
//user makes changes to FirstName
//user decides to cancel changes by closing form.
//>>> the object is still updated thanks to data-binding. this is bad. :(
```

Comment: What does your binding in `XAML` look like? If it's set to `TwoWay`, for example, it will automatically update any changes.

Comment: edited post to show xaml... Is it TwoWay by default?

Comment: If you don't use data structures that support change tracking you will probably have to implement something on your own. It may be as simple as storing a copy of the collection before any edits that you can use to revert the working set if a user cancels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the binding in your EditorForm to use UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit. This will not cause the property to automatically update when you change the value on the UI. Instead you will have to programatically trigger the binding to update the property.

```
<!--xaml-->
<TextBox x:Name="tbFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=MyObject.first_name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
<TextBox x:Name="tbLastName" Text="{Binding Path=MyObject.last_name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"  />
```

When your save button is clicked, you need to get the binding from the control and trigger an update:

```
var firstNameBinding = tbFirstName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
firstNameBinding.UpdateSource();
var lastNameBinding = tbLastName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
lastNameBinding.UpdateSource();
```

Comment: If you end up having a lot of fields, not just these 2, I believe you can use a BindingGroup to trigger all of the bindings at once, but you'll have to look into that. I haven't ever used BindingGroups before.